# LyX doesn't work (compile)

Tags: lyx, miktex

I reinstalled my LyX and it doesn't work...

First of all I see this message:

[image]

What I need to do to solve it? (I look over the internet and nothing was helpful).

At LyX itself I see this:

[image]

How can I install the document classes?

Nothing is working :-(

When I say "it doesn't work" - I mean - I can't process documents...

(I'm using Windows 10)

Comment: Your miktex is not complete. Did you install a miktex bundled with lyx or did you install miktex as standalone texsystem?

Comment: I do it both - with lyx and without lyx (I install with LyX, and when I saw the problem I uninstall it, and then I install it with LyX....) - But the problem still appear... :-(

Comment: Why do people constantly deinstall and reinstall? In any case: start the miktex package manager (admin), synchronize and check if there are missing packages that you can install. Check then also for updates.

Comment: How do I check if there are missing packages? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I think I did it, but it doesn't help at all....

Comment: What did you?  Show a sceenshot of the package manager with the package sorted by date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean the time they installed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischerצ what do you mean? the time they installed? It's a lot!!!
now I'm instaling all the packages... :-(

Comment: There are two installations programs for LyX. The biggest one should reinstall LyX + MikTeX, solving any problem of missing files or missing routes.

Comment: @Fran - as of 2018 the bundled install has a bug and it is no longer recommended see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437052/11626) and the [LyX wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/TeXLive) for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a similar problem in the past. It always seemed to happen if one installs LyX before MikTex...but it disappears when I start wih MikTex...also make sure that you have an suitable directory with access rights and stuff...
I hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain more please? So first of all install MikTex and then LyX? Because LyX including MikTex.... Thank you!

Comment: Uninstall both of your current LyX and MikTeX...get fresh and up to date setups of MikTeX and LyX...dont install LyX first...start with MikTeX...this procedure has solved the problem for me in the past